How do I add a background image to my splash screen on android created with react-native-bootsplash?
I am trying to add a background image to my splash screen in my react native app, on IOS I added it manually on android I am getting some weird behavior.
I am using react-native-bootsplash v5.4.1
I modified my styles.xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    </style>

     <style name="BootTheme" parent="Theme.BootSplash">
        <item name="bootSplashBackground">@color/bootsplash_background</item>
        <item name="bootSplashLogo">@drawable/bootsplash_logo</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bootsplash</item> //added this
        <item name="postBootSplashTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
    </style>

</resources>

And in my drawable I added bootsplash.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/splash" />
    </item>
</layer-list>

My issue is that first I am seeing the splash screen created with react-native-bootsplash (just a background color and the logo) and after it hides I see my background image.
How can I make my background image appear together with the original splash, is this causing a double splash?

I would suggest to move logo and background color to bootsplash.xml file too.
It will looks like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/bootsplash_background" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/splash" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bootsplash_logo" android:gravity="center" />
    </item>

</layer-list>

And second file will looks like:
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    </style>

     <style name="BootTheme" parent="Theme.BootSplash">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bootsplash</item>
    </style>

</resources>

